# Running CloudKit code in tests?

Tags: ios, testing, cloudkit

I’d like to write automated tests for my CloudKit code using the XCTest framework. The test case runs, gets a valid container object, gets a valid public database object, but then dies with an exception when I try to do anything real:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
    reason: 'Failed to establish valid container/bundleID information'
```

What I have tried so far:

- I’ve checked the `Info.plist` for my test target and the bundle ID there corresponds to the container ID.
- I have swizzled `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]` to make sure it returns the correct bundle ID.
- I have copied the iCloud entitlements from my main app’s target.

But I still get the exception. Is there a way to get the CloudKit code running in tests?

Comment: I got this error when my provisioning was not correct. Check that on the project settings page under identity no error is listed next to team, and that under capabilities the iCloud toggle is ON, the Cloudkit service is checked & with no invalid marked steps. After I fixed that, my tests run OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point is running the tests as “application tests”. I test a custom framework, so there’s no application to run the test suite in, no entitlements and therefore no CloudKit. I had to add a simple “Test Rig” target (an empty Cocoa app), set the entitlements there and set this test rig as a Bundle Loader and a Test Host for the test suite. Then the tests can use CloudKit just fine. Thank you for getting me on the right track, @Ward!